# Insertar a mi base de datos cargando un archivo Excel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, laravel-excel

**Hola** estoy tratando de cargar a mi `base de datos` por medio de `laravel excel 3.1`una información que llega desde un archivo `excel` el cual cargo por medio de un `input` adjunto mis tablas de la `base de datos`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el `codigo` por el cual estoy haciendo la insercion a mi `base de datos` con el archivo `Excel` :

Codigo controlador (import)

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\tbl_instrumentos;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel
 {

  public function model(array $row)
   {
     return new tbl_instrumentos([
     'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
     'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[1],
     'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[2],
  ]);
 }
}
```

Adicionalmente agrego el `código` de mi controlador principal:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{

 public function importExportView()
  {
  $data=DB::table('tbl_instrumentos')->orderBy('ins_id','DESC')
        ->get();
  return view('importar',compact('data'));
  }

  public function exportExcel($type) 
  {
   return Excel::download(new InstrumentosExport, 'instrumentos.'.$type);
  }

  public function importExcel(Request $request) 
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
    'select_file'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
  ]);
  Excel::import(new InstrumentosImport,$request->import_file);

  return back()->with('success', 'Datos Excel Importados 
    Satisfactoriamente.');
  }
```

El `import_file` que tengo en mi controlador (import) viene de mi vista por medio de un `input` el cual es el siguiente:

```
 <input type="file" name="import_file" />
```

En ese ejemplo que tengo solo estoy recogiendo 3 datos de mi `excel` pero quiero agregar mas datos, por lo tanto como se puede ver en la `base de datos` un instrumento tiene varias calibraciones entonces al momento de yo ingresar todos esos datos (pienso ingresar los datos del instrumento y la calibracion de una vez) como determino por medio de la `foranea` cual es el instrumento calibrado, e igualmente la marca y el tipo de instrumento que tambien se insertaran de una vez, o ingreso marca y tipo primero y luego lo otro?

Como podria estructurar esa parte , Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busca cuál es la `id` del modelo relacionado por el valor del campo que te trae el excel. Y en el modelo al que estás importando, inserta la `id` en vez del dato que trae el excel.

Por ejemplo, si en el excel tienes el nombre de la marca en la columna `3`, puedes usar [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) para buscar en tu modelo de marcas cuál es la `id` que corresponde a ese nombre, y si no existe la creas.

Algo así:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $marca = Marca::firstOrCreate([
        'mar_nombre' => $row[3]
    ]);

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        // ...
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);
}
```

Luego es lo mismo para las otras llaves foráneas.

---

#### [`firstOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

El método `firstOrCreate` intentará localizar un registro de base de datos utilizando los pares de 'columna/valor' dados (para tu caso creo que sería columna:`mar_nombre` y valor:`el que tengas en el excel, supongo que el nombre de la marca`) . Si el modelo no se puede encontrar en la base de datos, se insertará un registro con los atributos del primer parámetro (`mar_nombre`), junto con los del segundo parámetro opcional (no puse nada, porque en la tabla `tbl_marcas` sólo tienes `mar_nombre` y `mar_id`, donde supongo que `mar_id` es la llave primara autoincremental).

Comment: Disulpa ese firstOrCreate no me queda muy claro

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez agregué a la respuesta más info sobre como funciona  `firstOrCreate`. Para ser más específico necesitaría más información sobre cómo es tu archivo excel y los modelos y relaciones que tienes para las tablas que muestras en la imagen.

Comment: Puse el `firstOrcreate` y primero me pidio que pusiera el campo  `fillable` lo hice y ahora me sale el siguiente error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'mar_nombre' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tbl_marca` (`mar_nombre`) values (?))`

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez Ok, sí, [fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) es necesario para usar el método create. Y el error que te dá, es porque el valor que le pasas es `null`. Por favor lee o relee el comentario anterior. Lo siento pero no sé que tienes en el excel, en la columna 3 ni en ninguna de las otras, tampoco sé nada de tus modelos, y lo más probable es que el problema esté relacionado con eso. Es una respuesta general para una pregunta amplia, si quieres algo más específico... sé más específico.

Comment: Disculpa, en el `row[3]` tengo el nombre de la marca y mi modelo marca solo tiene lo siguiente `public $table="tbl_marca";
    protected $fillable = ['mar_id', 'mar_nombre'];`

Comment: Bueno, `'mar_id'` si es la llave primaria, no va en $fillable, va en `$primaryKey` como ya te comenté en otra pregunta. Y el `$row[3]` ¿tiene **siempre** el nombre de la marca? estás seguro que no hay aunque sea una fila del excel en que esté vacía esa columna? Porque el error te está diciendo claramente que estás intentando insertar `null` en algún momento.

Comment: Si amigo tienes razon, estaba llamando mal al `$row` fallo mio, bro muchisimas gracias te lo agradezco de corazon eres un genio, me haz ayudado mucho.

Comment: Oye, me sale el error de que la columna no puede ser null pero estoy seguro que el `excel` en la celda que tengo puesta si tiene dicha información