# Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{"tipo_id":2}'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Hola** me sale el error al momento de ingresar a mi `base de datos` ya que al campo que quiero agregarlo es una `foranea` pero me sale con ese formato `{{tipo_id:2}}` como podria convertir eso a un formato que pueda usar para ingresarlo a mi `base de datos`

Adjunto el codigo como estoy llamando al dato =

```
$tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::select('tipo_id')->where ('tipo_nombre','=',$row[14])->first();
```

El `$row[14]` viene de un archivo de `excel` que traigo por medio de la libreria `laravel excel 3.1`

Adjunto el `Codigo` de controlador donde estoy insertando:

```
class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel
 {

public function model(array $row)
{

    $id = Auth::id(); //trae el id del usuario logeado
    $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::select('tipo_id')->where ('tipo_nombre','=',$row[14])->first();
    $marca=tbl_marca::select('mar_id')->where('mar_nombre','=',$row[15])->first();
    //$tipo=DB::table('tbl_tipo_instrumento')->select('tipo_id')->where ('tipo_nombre','=',$row[14])->get();
    //$marca=DB::table('tbl_marca')->select('mar_id')->where('mar_nombre','=',$row[15])->get();

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[4],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[6],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row[1],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row[5],
        'ins_claseOexactitud' =>$row[6] ,
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row[7],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row[8],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row[9],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row[10],
        'ins_modelo' => $row[11],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row[12],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca,
    ]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Pues ahi dice que espera trabajar con datetime y lo que le esta llegando como valor no lo es

Comment: Porque sucede eso si el campo en mi base de datos es bigint?

Comment: first() te devuelve un objeto, no un integer, puedes hacer $tipo->tipo_id para obtener el integer, pero no nos muestras cómo estás insertando, solo cómo estás obteniendo algo de la BD

Comment: Ya adjunte el codigo de como hago la inserción @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Bueno, eso eso que te comenté `'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,`. Si estás seguro que  el campo en tu base de datos es bigint, pasale un integer, no un objeto. Igual con esas consultas en cualquier momento te puede devolver `null` dependiendo de lo que tengas en el excel, por eso cuando [preguntaste antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332751/insertar-a-mi-base-de-datos-cargando-un-archivo-excel/332818#332818) te sugerí que uses firstOrCreate.

Answer (score 0):

según entendí, es un id lo que tienes que guardar al tener las dos colecciones `$tipo` y `$marca`

ya solo tienes que guardar el ID de cada coleccion.

```
class InstrumentosImport implements ToModel
{

  public function model(array $row)
  {

    $id = Auth::id(); //trae el id del usuario logeado
    $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::select('tipo_id')->where ('tipo_nombre','=',$row[14])->first();
    $marca=tbl_marca::select('mar_id')->where('mar_nombre',$row[15])->first();
    //$tipo=DB::table('tbl_tipo_instrumento')->select('tipo_id')->where ('tipo_nombre','=',$row[14])->get();
    //$marca=DB::table('tbl_marca')->select('mar_id')->where('mar_nombre','=',$row[15])->get();

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[4],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[6],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row[1],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row[5],
        'ins_claseOexactitud' =>$row[6] ,
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row[7],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row[8],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row[9],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row[10],
        'ins_modelo' => $row[11],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row[12],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->id,
    ]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Al hacerlo de esa forma me sale el siguiente error `Trying to get property 'tipo_id' of non-object`

Comment: Entones no esta encontrando el tipo de instrumento, prueba con los log, después de buscar el tipo de intrumento coloca: \Log::info($tipo);  luego de que ejecutes busca en la carpeta de tu proyecto Storage > logs > Archivo con la fecha actual, y veras si esta consultando bien

Comment: seria de mucha ayuda si pudiéramos ver el valor que viene desde el excel de $row[14]

Comment: En el `$row[15]` el valor es el nombre de la marca en ese caso es `Mettler`

Comment: y el valor de $row[14]?

Comment: Es el nombre del tipo del instrumento `Balanza`